# The Unknown Drink

Tags: story, cipher

**On July 15, 2007, 10 people were killed after drinking an unknown substance laced with an unknown poison.**
At the crime scene was a USB with a single file, this picture:
[answers.png](http://initializesahib.github.io/answers.png)
However, the image was corrupted, and no one could see it.
On the wall, was a message:
**YOU IDIOTS THINK YOU KNEW MY PLAN**
**WELL I'LL GIVE YOU A CHANCE**
**YOU'LL NEED:**
**SOMETHING I HAVE A LOT OF**
**SOMETHING NONE OF US HAVE**
**SOMETHING I HAVE NONE OF**
**THE CREATOR OF AN ENGINE FOR A CERTAIN TEXT**
**AND EXCLAMATION MARKS**
You are a junior detective who is excited at the prospect of decoding this.
It took you months and months.... but you got the answer.

**What was the drink? And what was the poison it was laced with?**

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

Creator of an engine for a certain text:

> The drink was java.

Something none of us have:

> Time. The poison is something that's aged over time - not my area of expertise, so I couldn't tell you how that narrows anything down.

Exclamation marks:

> Also known as "bangs," as in gunshots. There's GSR involved in this potion of death.

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of those are correct. You ARE on the right track with "Java", though.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> PNG file contains following text at the beginning and at the end:
>
> ```
> FIILq2LRKlyMGCiKTJLVKiKjlPeujSnJs0ImGYy2ImGhMEi0QJBoJUExoOFdUIJQDLQYsQTkXZ1Qvxs6a1uPNq==
> ```
>
> and the following image between:
>
>   [image]

Comment: the text is slightly different at each end.  it appears to be be base64 data but does not decode to anything I can understand.

Comment: I think the all the text in bold would lead us to a key. Then, we can apply a Vigenere cipher to the wrapper strings, then base64 decode that and we'll have something understandable... maybe